# Reading text data from a file stored in Parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm saving large text files as objects in Parse. They are too large to save directly as text in a normal String column.

Later, I want to retrieve these files and process the text in JavaScript.

Here's the code I'm using to store the text in a Parse file:

```
// Inputs
var long_text_string = '...'; // A long string
var description      = '...'; // Description of this string

// Convert string to array of bytes
var long_text_string_bytes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < long_text_string.length; i++) {
    long_text_string_bytes.push(long_text_string.charCodeAt(i));
}

// Create Parse file
var parsefile = new Parse.File("long_text_string.txt", long_text_string_bytes);
parsefile.save({
    success: function() {
        // Associate file with a new object... 
        var textFileObject = new Parse.Object("TextFile");
        textFileObject.set('description', description);
        textFileObject.set('file', parsefile);
        textFileObject.save();
    }
});
```

How do I then retrieve the content of the data file, convert it back from bytes to string, and end up with it stored in a normal string variable in JavaScript?

## UPDATE

I've tried three different approaches, all to no avail...

### Method 1 [preferred]

**Use Parse commands to process the file**

It's simple to use the Parse JS API to retrieve my `TextFile` object, and use `parseFile = object.get('file');` to get the Parse file itself. The URL of the file is then `parseFile.url()`.

But then what? I can't do anything with that URL in JS because of cross-origin restrictions.

There is no [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#files-retrieving-file-contents) on how to use the JS API to access the byte data contained within the file. There appears to be an Android command, `getDataInBackground`, documented [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#files-the-parsefile), so I am hopeful there is a JS equivalent....

### Method 2

**Use the Parse REST API to fire a XMLHTTP request**

Unfortunately, it seems that Parse have not enabled CORS for their file URLs. I have tried the following code, adapted from a Parse.com blog post (blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/javascript-and-user-authentication-for-the-rest-api/):

```
var fileURL = textFileObject.get('file').url();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", fileURL, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", appId);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", restKey);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
};

var data = JSON.stringify({ message: "" });
xhr.send(data);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin '<my host>' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 403
```

A bit of a Google suggests that the file URLs are not CORS-enabled (parse.com/questions/access-control-allow-origin--2).

(Note that the above code works for a normal object request, it's only when you use the fileURL that it errors).

### Method 3

**Use a browser to circumvent cross-origin restrictions**

I can create a webpage with an empty iframe and set `iframe.src` to `parseFile.url()`. The content of the file appears on the web page. But I still end up with cross-origin issues when I try to access the DOM content of the iframe! Not to mention loading each file onto a webpage one by one is an incredibly substandard solution.

Comment: Load it with regular Ajax calls? Don't know if they allow cross-origin requests on those URLs...

Comment: I'm no expert with "regular Ajax calls", but there certainly is a cross-origin issue with trying to use non-Parse-specific techniques. The file URL is different from my web host, unsurprisingly, and hence there's not much I can do to access it. It loads OK into an iframe, but that's about as far as I got down that route. Hence why I'm looking for a Parse command that does the job "properly.Thanks for the input though.

Comment: The file being in a different domain does not necessarily mean you can't access it via Ajax. If they support CORS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), which they probably do for access to their API, then you could access it via Ajax.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - in theory it was bang on... but in practice, it didn't work. I got XMLHTTP requests working using the REST API, but it seems that the Parse.com URLs for files are not CORS-enabled. I've updated the question to reflect the three approaches I've tried so far, but ultimately I'm back to square one.

Comment: How big are your strings? A Parse object is limited to 128K, so you should have quite enough space to store the string directly in a Parse object (though it may be a separate object dedicated to holding just a single string, rather than an additional field in another object). If you go beyond that, you may be able to split the string and store as multiple Parse objects.

Comment: The strings are HTML pages (of real websites). The very first one I tried was too big to store as a string directly in Parse, so I immediately rejected this method. But you're right, it's probably time to go back to this. Splitting them up into chunks is probably the answer.

Comment: You may want to consider compression. [lz-string](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) seems to be an interesting candidate (though be sure to read things to the end of the page)